# MediaPlayer.java ICS Android

Tags: android, media-player

Where I can find source code of MediaPlayer class in ICS.
I have source code...but i cant find com.media package at all...
it's not in the same as in 2.2 or 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/media/MediaPlayer.java/) is the code of the 4.0.4_r1.2 version as you can see at the top of the page.
From that file you can navigate all the version released of [`MediaPlayer.java`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)